# Google Analytics and MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, google-analytics

I'm after a bit of guidance as to where to put the GA code.  Do I just put this into the Site.Master file and everything will be hunky-dory?  Or do I need to implement it in each View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put mine in the master page. Everything is hunky-dory.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the master page. Consider putting it in a separate placeholder so if need be you can override it in a view to turn it off. You should also put it at the bottom so it loads last.

Comment: the new GA code is asynchronous and Google recommend that you put it in the head tag.

Comment: @Ardman - really? http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55574

Comment: there are lots of articles stating it: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174090